# Read web.config file hosted in iis using c#

Tags: c#, .net, iis

i want to get all ports configured in IIS and their associated database user name that are in configuration file placed at wwwroot directory. anyone can help me how to read xml configuration against a port in IIS using c#.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.administration?view=iis-dotnet

Answer (score 2):

get all sites installed in IIS

```
ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager();

var sites = serverManager.Sites;
```

for getting ports

```
foreach(var site in sites)
{
    //if only one binding
    var port = site.Bindings[0].EndPoint.Port.ToString();
    //if more than one binding
    foreach(var binding in site.Bindings)
    {
        var port = binding.EndPoint.Port.ToString();
    }
}
```

getting web.config based on iis

```
var applicationRoot = site.Applications.First(a => a.Path == "/");
var virtualRoot = applicationRoot.VirtualDirectories.First(v => v.Path == "/");
```

then play with the `virtualRoot` path get details from site

```
var filePath = physicalPath + "\\Web.config";
var attributes = File.GetAttributes(filePath);
//if you need to update something remove readonly
if ((attributes & FileAttributes.ReadOnly) == FileAttributes.ReadOnly)
{
    // Make the file RW
    attributes = attributes &~ FileAttributes.ReadOnly;
    File.SetAttributes(filePath, attributes);
}
var fileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap { ExeConfigFilename = filePath };
var configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

var appSetting = configuration.AppSettings.Settings["key"].Value;
var connectionString = configuration.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings[connectionStringName];
```